# Fullscreen API; browser thinks I don't start with a user gesture

Tags: javascript, html, fullscreen, html5-fullscreen

I'm working on a custom video player using the HTML5 `video` element and I'm having trouble getting the full screen button to work with the [Fullscreen API](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Fullscreen_API).

When I click it, I get the error message:

```
Failed to execute 'requestFullscreen' on 'Element': API can only be initiated by a user gesture.
```

However, I am initiating the call to `requestFullscreen` with a user gesture... Unless I'm misunderstanding what constitutes a user gesture. A click on an element is a user gesture, isn't it?

I realize that there are a lot of questions about the Fullscreen API on SO, but it looks like many people want to initiate full screen mode without user interaction.

What am I doing wrong?

There is a [pen](http://codepen.io/VAggrippino/pen/vgZdaw) with this code, but I'm likely to change that when I find a solution. I won't change the code here.

Here's the code:

```js
/* Get our elements. */
const player = document.querySelector('.player');
const video = player.querySelector('.viewer');
const progress = player.querySelector('.progress');
const progressBar = player.querySelector('.progress__filled');
const toggle = player.querySelector('.toggle');
const skipButtons = player.querySelectorAll('[data-skip]');
const ranges = player.querySelectorAll('.player__slider');
const fullscreen = player.querySelector('.fullscreen');

let isFullScreen = false;

/* Build our functions */
function togglePlay() {
  const action = video.paused ? 'play' : 'pause';
  video[action]();
}

function updatePlayIcon() {
  toggle.classList.toggle('playing');
}

function skip() {
  video.currentTime += parseFloat(this.dataset.skip);
}

function handleRangeUpdate() {
  video[this.name] = this.value;
}

function handleProgress() {
  const percent = (video.currentTime / video.duration) * 100;
  progressBar.style.flexBasis = percent + '%';
}

function scrub(e) {
  const seconds = (e.offsetX / progress.offsetWidth) * video.duration;
  video.currentTime = seconds;
}

function toggleFullScreen() {
  if (isFullScreen) {
    console.log("exiting fullscreen");

    if (document.exitFullscreen) {
      document.exitFullscreen();
    } else if (document.mozCancelFullScreen) {
      document.mozCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.webkitCancelFullScreen) {
      document.webkitCancelFullScreen();
    } else if (document.msExitFullscreen) {
      document.msExitFullscreen();
    }

    console.log('removing fullscreen class');
    player.classList.remove('fullscreen');
  } else {
    console.log("entering fullscreen");

    if (player.requestFullscreen) {
      console.log('requestFullScreen');
      player.requestFullscreen(); // standard
    } else if (player.webkitRequestFullscreen) {
      console.log('webkitRequestFullscreen');
      player.webkitRequestFullscreen(Element.ALLOW_KEYBOARD_INPUT);
    } else if (player.mozRequestFullScreen) {
      console.log('mozRequestFullScreen');
      player.mozRequestFullScreen();
    } else if (player.msRequestFullscreen) {
      console.log('msRequestFullscreen');
      player.msRequestFullscreen();
    } else {
      console.error('Unable to find a fullscreen request method');
    }
    console.log('adding fullscreen class');
    player.classList.add('fullscreen');
  }
  isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
}

/* Hook up the event listeners */
video.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);
toggle.addEventListener('click', togglePlay);

video.addEventListener('play', updatePlayIcon);
video.addEventListener('pause', updatePlayIcon);
video.addEventListener('timeupdate', handleProgress);

skipButtons.forEach(button => button.addEventListener('click', skip));

ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('change', handleRangeUpdate));
ranges.forEach(range => range.addEventListener('mousemove', handleRangeUpdate));

let mousedown = false;
progress.addEventListener('click', scrub);
progress.addEventListener('mousemove', (e) => mousedown && scrub(e));
progress.addEventListener('mousedown', () => mousedown = true);
progress.addEventListener('mouseup', () => mousedown = false);

fullscreen.addEventListener('click', toggleFullScreen);

document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
```

```css
html {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

*,
*:before,
*:after {
  box-sizing: inherit;
}

html, body {
  height: 100%;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  display: flex;
  background: #7A419B;
  background: linear-gradient(135deg, #7c1599 0%, #921099 48%, #7e4ae8 100%);
  background-size: cover;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
}

.player {
  max-width: 750px;
  max-height: 100%;
  border: 5px solid rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  box-shadow: 0 0 20px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  position: relative;
  font-size: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
}

button.toggle.fullscreen::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f065";
}

.player.fullscreen .player__controls .toggle.fullscreen::before {
  content: "\f066";
}

/* This css is only applied when fullscreen is active. */

.player.fullscreen {
  max-width: none;
  max-height: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: black;
}

.player.fullscreen video {
  width: 100%;
}

.player__video {
  max-width: 100%;
  max-height: 100%;
}

.player__button {
  background: none;
  border: 0;
  line-height: 1;
  color: white;
  text-align: center;
  outline: 0;
  padding: 0;
  cursor: pointer;
  max-width: 50px;
}

.player__button:focus {
  border-color: #ffc600;
}

.toggle::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f04b";
}

.toggle.playing::before {
  font-family: "FontAwesome";
  content: "\f04c";
}

.player__slider {
  width: 10px;
  height: 30px;
}

.player__controls {
  display: flex;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  width: 100%;
  transform: translateY(100%) translateY(-5px);
  transition: all .3s;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.1);
}

.player:hover .player__controls {
  transform: translateY(0);
}

.player:hover .progress {
  height: 15px;
}

.player__controls > * {
  flex: 1;
}

.progress {
  flex: 10;
  position: relative;
  display: flex;
  flex-basis: 100%;
  height: 5px;
  transition: height 0.3s;
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.5);
  cursor: ew-resize;
}

.progress__filled {
  width: 50%;
  background: #ffc600;
  flex: 0;
  flex-basis: 0%;
}

.player__slider {
  position: relative;
}

.player__slider::after {
  content: attr(name);
  position: absolute;
  top: -2px;
  text-shadow: 1px 1px 1px 0 rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
  font-size: 0.8em;
}
/* unholy css to style input type="range" */

input[type=range] {
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  background: transparent;
  width: 100%;
  margin: 0 5px;
}

input[type=range]:focus {
  outline: none;
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-runnable-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.8);
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-webkit-slider-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
  -webkit-appearance: none;
  margin-top: -3.5px;
  box-shadow: 0 0 2px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
}

input[type=range]:focus::-wefbkit-slider-runnable-track {
  background: #bada55;
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-track {
  width: 100%;
  height: 8.4px;
  cursor: pointer;
  box-shadow: 1px 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 1px rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  background: #ffffff;
  border-radius: 1.3px;
  border: 0.2px solid rgba(1, 1, 1, 0);
}

input[type=range]::-moz-range-thumb {
  box-shadow: 0 0 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0), 0 0 0 rgba(13, 13, 13, 0);
  height: 15px;
  width: 15px;
  border-radius: 50px;
  background: #ffc600;
  cursor: pointer;
}
```

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<div class="player">
  <video class="player__video viewer" src="https://player.vimeo.com/external/194837908.sd.mp4?s=c350076905b78c67f74d7ee39fdb4fef01d12420&profile_id=164"></video>
  <div class="player__controls">
    <div class="progress">
      <div class="progress__filled"></div>
    </div>
    <button class="player__button toggle" title="Toggle Play"></button>
    <input type="range" name="volume" class="player__slider" min="0" max="1" step="0.05" value="1">
    <input type="range" name="playbackRate" class="player__slider" min="0.5" max="2" step="0.1" value="1">
    <button data-skip="-10" class="player__button"><i class="fa fa-step-backward"></i> 10s</button>
    <button data-skip="25" class="player__button">25s <i class="fa fa-step-forward"></i></button>
    <button class="player__button toggle fullscreen"></button>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem was that my `toggleFullScreen` function was being called twice when I clicked on the full screen button. I saw it while I was replying to Bibek Khadka's answer. The first time was when I clicked the button and the second time was when the full-screen mode actually changed because of these event listeners...

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
document.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreen);
```

It would go to fullscreen mode, then back so quick that I didn't see the change. I believe the second time called the Fullscreen API method (technically) without a user gesture and that's why I got the error message.

The solution (for now at least) is to create a separate function for changing classes and the variable I'm using to track whether or not I'm in full screen mode ...

```
function toggleFullScreenClasses() {
  player.classList.toggle('fullscreen');
  isFullScreen = !isFullScreen;
}
```

... then I don't use that to handle the click on the button. I only use it to handle the actual fullscreenchange event...

```
document.addEventListener('fullscreenchange', toggleFullScreenClasses);
document.addEventListener('mozfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreenClasses);
document.addEventListener('webkitfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreenClasses);
document.addEventListener('msfullscreenchange', toggleFullScreenClasses);
```

I know this is sloppy, but it solves the problem for now. I previously tried using the [:fullscreen](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/:fullscreen) pseudo-class, but I had some difficulty and I switched to the more familiar method of toggling classes and variables. I need to take another look at that.

Answer (score 0):

I am no expert...just someone with free time :)

your `const player = document.querySelector('.player');` is an element and trying to `player.requestFullscreen();` gives you the errror. Modify your code so that the api call is made from something like `player.onclick().requestFullscreen();` maybe. Sorry if I wasn't that helpful.

Comment: I appreciate your time. Basically, that's what I'm already doing. The correct syntax for your recommendation would be `player.onclick = toggleFullScreen;` where `toggleFullScreen` is my function with the necessary vendor-prefixed `requestFullscreen` calls. I don't want to listen to clicks on `player`, though. If I did, clicking on any button or even the video would toggle full screen. I only want to listen to clicks on the full screen button and that's what I'm doing. This is an alternate syntax that does exactly what you recommended: `fullscreen.addEventListener('click', toggleFullScreen);`